# how to show non matching mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

i m trying to create school fees recipt system

i create two table in phpmyadmin 1 is admission and 2nd is fees

1.admission
i create admission php form when i fill the admission form all detail save in admission table

2.fees
the same thing i create it in fees page

in admission table have all student info who are study in our school

and in fees table all info of student who paid the fees of the month

but now i want student fees report who are paid and who are not paid the fees

this code showing only paid student report

but i want both result who are paid and who are not paid how can i do this

please help me to fix this issue

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("student", $con);

    echo "<div id='non-printable'><table class='sortable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>No</th> <th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>GRN</th> <th>Reference</th><th>Class</th><th>Roll No</th><th>Fees</th></tr>";

    // get results1 from database
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT fees.id,fees.name,fees.date,fees.grn,fees.reference,fees.class,fees.rollno,fees.fees, admission.mothername "." FROM fees, admission ". " WHERE fees.name = admission.name AND fees.date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-14' AND fees.class='6' order by class ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['grn'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['reference'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['class'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['rollno'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['fees'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['mothername'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 

        //Increment the value of the Total_total variable
        //by the salary value of one row till the while loop finishes
        $Total_fees=$Total_fees+$row['fees'];
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>Total</td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $Total_fees .'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";  

    // close table>
    echo "</table>";


    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: i would personally split in two query and use some if condition, if student_id exist in table fees -> paid else not paid i can write it down for you if needed

Comment: yes i needed how can i fix this code plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATED`

```
<?php
    echo "<div id='non-printable'><table class='sortable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>No</th> <th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>GRN</th> <th>Reference</th><th>Class</th><th>Roll No</th><th>Fees</th></tr>";

    $dbserver = 'localhost'; 
    $dblogin  = 'root';
    $dbpassword = '';  
    $dbname = 'student';

    //opening connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    //opening connection
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name`, `mothername` FROM `admission` WHERE `class` = '6' ORDER BY `name` ASC") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while($student = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $subresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `fees` WHERE `name` = '".$student['name']."' AND `date` BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-14'") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        if($row = $subresult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>Student</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['grn'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['reference'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['class'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['rollno'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['fees'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $student['mothername'] . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td>' . $student['name'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td> didn\'t pay any fee.</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
            echo '</table>';

mysqli_close($mysqli); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT fees.id, fees.name, fees.date, fees.grn, 
   fees.reference, fees.class, fees.rollno, fees.fees, admission.mothername ".
      "FROM admission LEFT JOIN fees ON fees.name = admission.name". 
    "WHERE fees.date BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-14' AND fees.class='6' 
    order by class ASC");
```

Use the Left join so you can get all the rows of admission table and the corresponding rows 
of fees table. In this way you can get the blank data of fee table also.

Comment: @user2260431 ohh sorry I forgot to add the ON clause. I have added. now try.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in c:\xampp\htdocs\student\feesreports\view.php on line 21 now showing this error and line no 21 is  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))